# Get array with AJAX request and pass it into a php array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, arrays

I'm struggling with the next problem: I have an ajax request that passes a variable to a PHP file. The PHP processes the variable and returns with an array. I need to get back that array so I used the AJAX success callback function but I can only print out the array, nothing more. I want to use that array.

```
$.ajax({
    method:  'POST',
    url:  "process.php",
    data: { data: data},
    success: function(array)
    {
        <?php echo $GLOBALS['glob']; ?> = data;
    }
});
```

Even though if I ref to $GLOBALS['glob'] later, it says its an undefined variable. :S please help!

Comment: what is glob variable?

Comment: That is supposed to be the global var i want to use later on.

Comment: `PHP` = server side. `Javascript(jQuery)` = client side. You can't pass anything to **PHP** through javascript unless using AJAX as it is processed before your client side code.

Comment: exact duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Answer (score 1):

On succes you assign the variable as "array" and when you try to put it in the php array u say the variable is named "data". 
that's your first problem.

```
$.ajax({
    method:  'POST',
    url:  "process.php",
    data: { data: data},
    success: function(**array**)
    {
        <?php echo $GLOBALS['glob']; ?> = **data**;
    }
});
```

also you try to use php on client side.. 
normal javascript fires after your page is loaded and the variable is allready filled on page load. in this case you cant use the variable anymore.

And i just noticed this

```
$.ajax({
    method:  'POST',
    url:  "process.php",
    data: { data: data},
    success: function(**array**)
    {
    <?PHP echo $GLOBALS['glob']; ?> = data 
}
});
```

You end the variable without assigning it 
it should be

```
<?PHP echo $GLOBALS['glob'] = ?> data  <?PHP ; ?>
```

but as i said php scripts are executed before javascript so when the server reads the file it only says

echo $GLOBALS['glob'] = ;

Comment: Yes I found out the same. But what can I do with this then.?

Comment: You could put it in a javascript array and send that to a ajax handling file.. i don't know what you want to do with it

Answer (score 0):

Try sending a json array from your business logic.

Answer (score 0):

IN your php file you need to return json string and in success callback function you can get the object you are passing through server side

Like in php file, after all processing at the end convert the array to json string

```
json_encode($array);
```

and in your success call back function try to debug `console.log(array)`

Comment: I do get the array, or the array content if I want, still I want to copy the array into a PHP array or something, so I will be able to use this array not just write out in process.php and callback

Comment: So why not you assign this array to your global var in php file itself instead of returning back as a array

Comment: the process.php file is a different file and I need the array in my other php file where the AJAX request is located.